# Saving LayoutManager

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

```
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LayoutTest extends JFrame {

    public LayoutTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton = new JButton();

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                LayoutManager tempGroupLayout = jPanel1.getLayout();
                jPanel1.setLayout(layoutManager2);
                layoutManager = layoutManager2;
                layoutManager2 = tempGroupLayout;
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).
                addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup().
                addContainerGap(286, Short.MAX_VALUE).
                addComponent(jButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)));
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).
                addComponent(jButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 442, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        layoutManager = jPanel1Layout;

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout2 = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1Layout2.setHorizontalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout2.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).
                addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout2.createSequentialGroup().
                addComponent(jButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)));
        jPanel1Layout2.setVerticalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout2.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).
                addComponent(jButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 442, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        layoutManager2 = jPanel1Layout2;
        getContentPane().add(jPanel1);
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new LayoutTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    private JButton jButton;
    private JPanel jPanel1;
    private LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private LayoutManager layoutManager2;
}
```

This code does not work, why?
But if I each time create a layout in actionListener, it will work.

Comment: just note that if you `import javax.swing.X` you can use X directly (for example `BorderLayout` instead of `javax.swing.BorderLayout`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to include a call to `validate()` after switching the layoutmanager.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    LayoutManager tempGroupLayout = jPanel1.getLayout();
    jPanel1.setLayout(layoutManager2);
    getContentPane().validate();  // <= added line
    layoutManager = layoutManager2;
    layoutManager2 = tempGroupLayout;
}
```

Note: In the code posted there are missing some lines (e.g. initialization of jButton).

Comment: @itun what do you mean by "It does not work"? It does not compile? It does not show the button? If you click it does not change layout?

Comment: I push the button, but it does not change the layout

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Edited the line (should be validate instead of invalidate).

Comment: Ohhh!! Thank you very mush. I note you are patient and do not throw words to the wind, thank you.